# Pure java app port to glassfish

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, glassfish

I have an application written in pure/basic Java without GUI. I have three classes with main methods, so each of them can run for themselves. Now I run them with ant in specific order.

In glassfish I deployed Web application only with RESTful service.

What I want to do now is to transfer the three classes into glassfish, so I will call them in exact same order as before from RESTful service.

I watched series of videos on youtube on Java EE 6 APIs, but I didn't find anything that would help transfer pure Java application to glassfish. Should I use EJB API for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special to do. Just package the three classes into the `.war` file with your web service. When the web service method is called, create an instance of each class and call the appropriate method.

Of course you could also create EJBs for each class and inject an instance of each class into the web service class.

Comment: At the end I have considered this advice. It works for me and it seems simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would image that in the simplest form you can create servlet for each class that you normally call on the command line. Then, indeed you can pack them into a war file and deploy into glassfish. You do not have to use glassfish, by the way. You can use tomcat, jetty or any other servlet containers.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want the applications to run without user interaction like a human being clicking on a page. Create a singleton ejb which will be created as soon as the application is uploaded to the webserver, in the singleton create instances of your classes and call a method which should replicate the behaviour of the main method in each class.

```
`@Startup  
@Singleton  
public class StartupBean {  
private MyClass obj;  
private MyClass2 obj2;  
@PostConstruct  
initializeMyClasses(){  
obj = new MyClass();  
obj.start();//the start method contains code copy pasted from main  
obj2 = new MyClass2();  
obj2.start();`
```